# How to use RPAD in SAS?

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to add right zeros to a variable in a SQL step in SAS, I am using the RPAD statement which belongs to Oracle, however in SAS this statement does not work.
It would be very helpful if someone could support me.

Answer (score 3):

In SAS there is not a direct equivalent; you'd do something like

```
proc sql;
  select name, cats(name,'00000')
    from sashelp.class;
quit;
```

Or, you can use `repeat` which repeats a character a certain number of times.

```
proc sql;
  select name, cats(name,repeat('0',4))
    from sashelp.class;
quit;
```

Finally, all SAS variables are de facto right padded with spaces, so if the variable is `'###     '` you could do

```
proc sql;
  select name, translate(name,'0',' ')
    from sashelp.class;
quit;
```

Assuming you wanted to fully pad the right side with 0's.